# Checking if word is in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a .csv file with key/value pairs. Im trying to check if a given key is in the file by calling my dictionary but i have an error that i don't quite understand. Any help appreciated!

```
  def Dictionary(x):

     wDictionary = open('file.csv', 'r')
     for line in wDictionary:
           mylist = line.split(',')


  def main():

     x = input('enter text:')
     cd = Dictionary(x)
     if x in cd:
          print('yes')

  main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "7.py", line 15, in <module>
        main()
     File "7.py", line 12, in main
        if x in cd:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: You could also use the module "csv", it makes reading and writing csv files very easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not returning from `Dictionary(x)`, `cd` is set to `None`. Hence the error.

Bunch of other issues: I shall let you fix theindentation yourself.

```
def Dictionary(x):

     wDictionary = open('file.csv', 'r')
     mylist = []
     for line in wDictionary.readlines():
           mylist.append(line.split(','))
     return mylist


 def main():

     x = input('enter text:')
     cd = Dictionary(x)
     for line in cd:
         if x in line:
             print('yes')

 main()
```

Also, you dont need to send the parameter `x` into the function as you are not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in Dictionary(x), so Python does not know what to do when you ask it to iterate over cd.